# MySQL showing non-linear behavior for a simple insert

Tags: mysql, performance

I've come across a symptom in MySQL which got me baffled. First, the time it takes to INSERT a certain amount of records changes non-linearily with the amount of records. Second, the time also depends on the size of table, even when it has no indexes.

First, the tables (both MyISAM)

```
mysql> desc articles;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uuid           | varchar(250) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
...snip unrelated columns...
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc articles_groups;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| article_id   | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| group_id     | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| seq_num      | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| article_uuid | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Both tables contain about 15 million records with little fragmentation; I need to combine some data from the tables, so I create a temporary table:

```
mysql> create temporary table aga (aid int, agid int);
```

Nothing fancy; no indexes or primary keys.

Then I insert data int `aga` by combining data from the other tables:

```
mysql> insert into aga (aid,agid) select articles.id,articles_groups.id FROM
  articles,articles_groups where articles.uuid=articles_groups.article_uuid AND 
  articles_groups.id >= 0 AND articles_groups.id < 10000;
Query OK, 9999 rows affected (0.50 sec)
```

I've limited the number of records because a straight insert takes way too long. Now comes the interesting part. Look at the following table on how long the inserts take, depending on the number of records:

```
 articles_groups.id        Time (seconds)  
 -------------------------+--------------
 0 - 10K                  | 0.50
 10K - 20K                | 0.47
 20K - 30K                | 0.47
 30K - 50K                | 0.92
 50K - 100K               | 2.28
 100K - 200K              | 35.87 (!)
 200K - 300K              | 33.87
 300K - 500K              | 96.76
 500K - 510K              | 8.81 (eh?)
 510K - 520K              | 5.89 
 1000K - 1010K            | 4.75
 2000K - 2010K            | 10.14
 2010K - 2020K            | 9.02
```

Obviously it takes longer to insert more records, but there's a big jump when going from 50K inserts to 100K inserts. And 200K inserts take triple the time, not double. I could understand this if the `aga` table has indexes, but it doesn't.

After deleting the records from `aga` and performing the last insert again, it just takes 0.68 seconds, so clearly there is a relation to the size of the table and not the articles_groups.id (which is what I thought at first).

This is on a Linux machine with MySQL 5.1.46; quad core, 8 GB RAM; MySQL uses about 1.3 GB RAM.

Now as to my questions:

- Appearantly there is a 'wall' between 50K and 100K inserts for this particular query. Is there an easy way to find the optimal number of inserts, other than trial and error?
- If I would split the query into 10K batches as I have done above and run them in sequence, would that be faster than 1 query with no limits?
- Why does the time depend on the table size, even without indexes?

Comment: Your analysis doesn't mean a great deal. Much of the difference will be due to caching "After deleting the records from aga and performing the last insert again, it just takes 0.68 seconds" -- so cached in memory!, plus write bottleneck and/or writeback cache saturation on the disk. Is is a physical machine or a VM?

Comment: Physical machine. Yes, of course smaller batches will be cached on disk. But a jump from 2.28 to 35 seconds is not just from writing to disk. For what it's worth, the database file for `aga` on disk after 800K inserts is 6.2 megabytes. Hardly a harddisk bottleneck....